# UFT - How to get URL of a newly opened web page

Tags: qtp

I am clicking on a button on one page, which opens a report page in new tab.
The new tab is visible, but I'm not able to fetch the URL of the new page.

I'm using Browser("B").Page("P").GetROProperty("URL") to get the URL, but is returning "about:blank".

I think the new tab is not in focus even though it is visible.
So my question is:
1. How to bring the new page in focus?
2. How to fetch the URL of the new page?

Answer (score 1):

Try This might help..

In order to get the current URL you need to get the URL property of Page.

```
SystemUtil.Run "http://www.google.com"
url = Browser("micclass:=Browser").Page("micclass:=Page").GetRoProperty("url")
print url
```

Comment: Question is to find the URL of the page opened in new TAB

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Browser("CreationTime:=1").GetROProperty("OpenURL")
```

and see what that produces. Tabs are treated as separate browser objects and opening a new one creates a new browser object.

If the newly opened tab has a static identifier (i.e., the title is static, or a child object will always be present), I'd recommend using that since CreationTime can cause problems if you end up opening other tabs/browsers or one is already open when you kick off the action.